# Integrating check on memory leak into C code for autograding

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, malloc

I want to integrate into my C code a flag that is e.g. 1 if a memory leak occurs, and 0 if not. I need this sort of functionality to auto-grade student assignments in a course I am teaching. I don't need to know *where* the memory leak is, just whether one occurs in the runtime of the executable. For informative tracing/debugging, Valgrind is my go-to, but I am reluctant to parse Valgrind text output for grading.

I have experimented with:

- `mcheck.h` - `mtrace()` requires the use of an environment variable which gets a little hairy because of my autotesting setup (and getting a group of 300 first year students to run shell commands, which they have a weird resistance to)
- `malloc.h` - `mallinfo()` on a memory-clean executable has the same information as when I run it for a particular memory-unclean executable

Comment: You might consider https://github.com/vmware/chap

Comment: Thanks! It looks a little too "heavy" for it to be easily packaged for student personal use (e.g. on their personal machines). I guess I had been hoping that someone knew a `mallinfo()` trick that could give me the info I need :(

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value of valgrind. By default valgrind returns whatever the process under test returns. But this can be changed to return a specific value if valgrind detects an error.

The [valgrind manual](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.options) explains that best:

> --error-exitcode= [default: 0]
>
> Specifies an alternative exit code to return if Valgrind reported any errors in the run. When set to the default value (zero), the return value from Valgrind will always be the return value of the process being simulated. When set to a nonzero value, that value is returned instead, if Valgrind detects any errors. This is useful for using Valgrind as part of an automated test suite, since it makes it easy to detect test cases for which Valgrind has reported errors, just by inspecting return codes.

Comment: Hmmm, this is helpful, thank you. Ideally, I also want to provide a .c file that students can compile with as part of a test suite so they can run the tests before submitting (and they can get a message there that memory is an issue). I will be explicitly asking them to run Valgrind, but I thought it would be cute to have it bundled into my tester...

Comment: @bobthefairycat There's nothing stopping you from writing a wrapper for valgrind that just returns PASS or FAIL.

Comment: Interesting, I will look into that. Thanks!